# On putnam A2 2021

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, contest-math

Today I got an email saying I got 2/10 points on the putnam problem A2 from last years Putnam :(https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2021.pdf). I was a little surprised because I thought I had quite a rigorous proof. I'd appreciate if anyone here can maybe spot where my argument is wrong. For those who cannot access the link here is the problem: Define $$g(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} ((x+1)^{{r+1}}-x^{r+1})^{\frac1r},$$ for $x >0$. Find $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{g(x)}{x}. $$
Anyway here's my argument: We can write the given function $$((x+1)^{{r+1}}-x^{r+1})^{\frac{1}{r}}$$ as
$$ ((x+1)^{{r+1}}-x^{{r+1}})^{\frac{1}{r}} =(r+1)^{\frac{1}{r}}(x+\xi_{x}) ,$$
where $\xi_{x} \in (0,1).$ Indeed, this follows from the mean value theorem applied the function $h(t)=t^{r+1}$ on the interval $(x,x+1)$. Taking logarithms of the above equation shows that $g(x)$ tends to $e(x+\xi_{x})$ as $r$ tends to 0. Thus by squeeze theorem and the fact that $|\xi_{x}| \leq 1$ gives that $\frac{g(x)}{x} $ tends to $e$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Please include the question directly in your post instead of relying on an external link.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I do not see how that application of the MVT works.  Surely you would need $h(t)=t^{1/(r+1)}$ not $h(t)=t^{r+1}$.

Comment: @David Sorry it's a typo I fixed it.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Fixed.

Comment: @Marc Have you tried $$\int_{t}^{t+1}x^{r}dx-\frac{\left(\left(x+1\right)^{r+1}-x^{r+1}\right)}{r+1}=0$$ ?

Comment: I think a flaw in this argument is that $\xi_x=\xi_{r,x}$ in principle depends on $r$. Seems like it is not much trouble to correct the argument to account for this, but maybe that is why you only received partial points.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 Ah I see the issue. I think if we take the well-definedness of $g(x)$ as a given then a trivial modification of the argument proves it. Else, I don't know how this argument could be adapted to show g(x) is well defined.

Comment: If you look at [Kiran Kedlaya's second solution](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2021s.pdf), that's similar to what you are thinking of here (where you switched up the $r$ and $x$, and they justified why it could be done).